# Start Process within Windows Container as a domain user

Tags: windows, docker, containers, windows-container, gmsa

I have a Windows 2019 container started with a valid CredentialSpec from a valid working gMSA account.  It currently hosts a .NET 4.x application on IIS with Windows Authentication working just great.  I can also execute `nltest` commands successfully and communicate to the domain controller.

I want to run a Job or Process as a domain user (MyDomain\UserABC).  All of my attempts have failed:

1. Execute `start-process` with a credential object errors out with:

```
he security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship.
```

2. Using a scheduled job as `NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService` fails to access the web because it is not using the gMSA credentials but the Network Service credentials.
3. Create a scheduled job with a Domain User results in the same error as above:

```
he security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship.
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like cached credentials. Maybe you can take a look on this link:

[Site single Domain](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-server-for-it-pro/the-security-database-on-the-server-does-not-have-a-computer/m-p/89545)